# Mouse moves as expected but cannot select or click (after a recent update) [Arch Linux on Virtualbox]

Tags: virtualbox, mouse, archlinux, xorg, input-devices

In an `Arch Linux` VM on `Virtualbox`, the mouse is present and moves as expected, however it cannot select or click. It is a recent behavior after an update.

According to this [post](https://www.quora.com/Why-can-I-move-my-mouse-but-cannot-click-in-a-VirtualBox-with-Ubuntu), it could be related to `ZAxisMapping` settings (needed to be `6 7` instead of `4 5 6 7`). I found this parameter in two files:

- /lib/Xorg
- /lib/xorg/modules/input/mouse_drv.so

however, these files are not editable. Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: It seems that the problem has been resolved with the recent update. The current updated versions of the packages:
xf86-input-mouse 1.9.3-1
xorg-server 1.20.0-9
xorg-server-common 1.20.0-9
xorg-server-xvfb 1.20.0-9
xorg-server-xwayland 1.20.0-9